# Lower bound $\Omega$ grows quicker than upper bound $O$ of a recurrence relation $T(n)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relation

In my analysis of algorithms class we were given the following recurrence relation:

\begin{eqnarray}
T(n) &=&
\begin{cases}
    T\left(\displaystyle\frac{n}{2}\right) + 1, &n \ \mbox{is even number}& \\
    2T\left(\displaystyle\frac{n-1}{2}\right),　&n \ \mbox{is odd number}&
\end{cases} \nonumber \\
T(1) &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

I have proved by iteration (expand) that when $n = 2^k$ (always the even case), $T(n) = O(\log{n})$; when $n = 2^{k+1}-1$ (always the odd case), $T(n) = \Omega(n)$.

Is this actually possible? After looking at some other posts, I am thinking this is possibly because the $\Omega(n)$ obtained here is the lower bound runtime of the worst case scenario, and the $O(\log{n})$ is the upper bound runtime of the best case?

Am I confusing something? Or is there any other conclusion can be drawn from the result that $T(n) = O(\log{n})$ and $T(n) = \Omega(n)$ for the recurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recurrence satisfies neither $T(n) = O(\log n)$ nor $T(n) = \Omega(n)$.

What does hold is that there exists an infinite sequence of values $n_k$ such that $T(n_k) \leq C\log n_k$, and another infinite sequence of values $m_\ell$ such that $T(m_\ell) \geq c m_\ell$, where $C,c>0$ are some constants.

The definitions of big O and big Omega require such inequalities to hold *for all large enough $n$*, rather than for infinitely many values.

---

A similar situation is that of *partial limits* and *limits superior and inferior*. Consider the sequence $\sin n$ (where the angle is measure in radians). For each $x \in [-1,1]$, we can find an infinite sequence $n_k$ such that $\sin n_k \to x$. These are the *partial limits* of the sequence. The limit superior of the sequence is $1$, and its limit inferior is $-1$.

Similarly, in your case, $\Theta(\log n)$ and $\Theta(n)$ are "partial asymptotic limits", in the sense that there is an infinite sequence $n_k$ such that $An_k \leq T(n_k) \leq Bn_k$ for some $A,B>0$, and another infinite sequence $m_\ell$ such that $C \log m_\ell \leq T(m_\ell) \leq D \log m_\ell$ for some $C,D>0$. The "asymptotic limit superior" is $O(n)$, since $T(n) = O(n)$ but $T(n)$ is not $O(f(n))$ for any $f(n) = o(n)$. Similarly, the "asymptotic limit inferior" is $\Omega(\log n)$, since $T(n) = \Omega(\log n)$ but $T(n)$ is not $\Omega(g(n))$ for any $g(n) = \omega(\log n)$.

(Showing that $T(n) = O(n)$ and that $T(n) = \Omega(\log n)$ requires an argument.)

---

A sequence such as $\sin n$ has no limit. Similarly, $T(n)$ has no "asymptotic limit", that is, there is no "nice" function $h(n)$ such that $T(n) = \Theta(h(n))$ (we can define "nice" in various ways, for example a logarithmico-exponential function, that is, a function which can be expressed using arithmetic operations, $\log$ an $\exp$).

Comment: I got the "limits" idea on the $\sin{n}$ analogue but am not quite sure when applied to the recurrence. So instead of numerical values, the limits here are the Landau notations, that I could possibly also find another infinite sequence $n_k$ s.t. $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ being one of the "partial asymptotic limits" of the recurrence? Can I say for this recurrence, $O(n)$ is the tight upper bound and $\log{n}$ the tight lower bound? Or can I say, if $T(n)$ represents the runtime, this recurrence's worst case runtime is $\Theta(n)$ or $O(n)$, and best case runtime $\Theta(\log{n})$ or $O(\log{n})$?

Comment: A recurrence doesn’t have a runtime.

Comment: I just had a look again at my textbook. Will it be correct to say instead that, $T(n) = O(n)$ and $T(n) = \Omega(\log{n})$, with $O(n)$ and $\Omega(\log{n})$ being tight upper bound and tight lower bound, respectively? Or, the recursive algorithm with this recurrence relation, has worst case running time $\Theta(n)$ or $O(n)$, and best case running time $\Theta(\log{n})$ or $O(\log{n})$?

Comment: Worst-case and best-case running times are functions of $n$. They refer to the variety of different inputs of length $n$. It's not about different values of $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I have one more question. How did we come to the conclusion that $O(n)$ is the "asymptotic limit superior" while $\Omega(\log{n})$ is the "asymptotic limit inferior"? Because we just managed to find two infinite sequences which can be bounded by $\log{n}$ and $n$ individually, there may exist some other infinite sequences that are bounded by other $f(n)$. Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: The sequence along which $T(n) = \Omega(n)$ shows that $T(n)$ is not $O(f(n))$ for any $f(n) = o(n)$. So the new information here is not that $O(n)$ is a tightest bound, but rather that it is a bound at all! Showing that $T(n) = O(n)$ requires an argument. Same for $T(n) = \Omega(\log n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and explanation to someone who just starts learning algorithms! The idea of "partial asymptotic limits" actually solved one puzzle I had when solving the problem: when I used Master Theorem for $n = 2^k$, I found $T(n) = \Theta(\log{n})$ but through induction I obtained $T(n) = O(\log{n})$ instead.

Comment: For $n = 2^k$, you do get $\Theta(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

You calculated “Big-Theta for n = power of two - 1”. That’s not a useful thing. Try calculating T(n) for n = (4^k - 1) / 3 and be surprised. (Write n down in binary first). Or n = 3 * (8^k - 1) / 7 where T(n) ≈ n^(2/3).

You found the values for a good case and for a bad case. You’ll have to prove they are lower and upper bound.

Comment: I don't quite understand what does "Write n down in binary first" mean and how to go from there. But I managed to prove by induction that when $n = \frac{4^k-1}{3}$, $T(n) = \Omega(\sqrt{n})$. I think this makes $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ one of the "partial asymptotic limits" as mentioned by another user in this question. It is interesting to know the example sequences you've given.